# Structure of a folder in Window?

Tags: c, windows

I'm reading "The C Progamming Language" and practice a code to print out the file names inside a folder. Here's the snippet of code from the author for the UNIX system:

```
#ifndef DIRSIZ
#define DIRSIZ 14
#endif
struct direct /* directory entry */
{
ino_t d_ino; /* inode number */
char d_name[DIRSIZ];
} direct
...
struct direct dirbuf;  
while(read(afiledescriptor, (char*) &dirbuf, sizeof(dirbuf))
== sizeof(dirbuf)){/* do sth with dirbuf */}
```

The problem is I don't know how directory file descriptors in Windows are constructed and thus can't specify the third parameter (the bytes to read `parameter,DIRSIZE`) in`_read`. Anyone can help? Thank you.

Comment: and how is that related?

Comment: The book said that a folder in UNIX is a file with a structure of headers that have the type of 'direct' above,with 1 inode number and one name of the file it contains. Each header for each file. So the code read the folder,header by header,and print out the names of the files. But I need to know the size of a header to do that,in this case of the UNIX system is 14,as the book write. I don't know the size of a header in Window.

Comment: @Best_Name: Windows is not Unix. And to be honest, the description in the book you have there is not entirely correct. There are different varieties of Unix (AT&T System-V, BSD, Solaris, MacOS X (yes, the Apple OS at its core is a Unix)) and they all use slightly different directory entry structures. That's why you never should list files using the method you have there. Because of that variety a API was specified in the POSIX standard, which is supported across all the *nix OS-es, and Linux: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html – note that you **don't** define dirent yourself!

Answer (score 3):

In general, file system function calls are very different between Linux/Unix and Windows. You simply cannot apply your Unix/Linux compatible C code on Windows. For everything regarding the file system in the Windows world, refer to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

To list files in directories for instance, there's a nice example on MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

In general, you will be working with [FindFirstFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [FindNextFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Read the documentation on MSDN, the examples and so on.

When coming from the Unix world you will have to get used to how things work on Windows. That takes some time, but it's worth the effort I guess.

Comment: Can you give me a more specific link? I'm new

Comment: Can you tell me what you are trying to achieve? As far as I know, there's no exact equivalent to the struct you are reffering to on Windows,...
There seems to be a Windows implementation though:
[Here](http://www.two-sdg.demon.co.uk/curbralan/code/dirent/dirent.html)

Comment: I'm trying to write a program that prints out all the file' names inside a directory

Comment: See the modified answer for details.